# what is the way to connect postgresql with android in ubuntu

Tags: android, python, web-services, postgresql, ubuntu-10.04

I am using postgresql in ubuntu, and now i am working on python. I want to connect postgresql with an android application. Is there any way to connect postgresql with an android application?
                  Any reply would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

***Better way is to Use RestFUL API or WebService as front end for your Android device to connect to your PostgreSQL backend***. I am not sure if it is possible to directly connect your android device to postgre SQL.

Comment: @prashant, I guess you want to do your API in Python. There is Django Piston for all things API. If you dont want a bulldozer, there is CherryPy (or any other Python framework). I know a busy (millions of requests per day) Android service that was served by Piston and then CherryPy.